# Why does free error occurs in operator overloading?

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, iteration

I've overloaded `operator*` for `std::string` class, but in this case:

```
std::string operator*(std::string a, unsigned b) //bad
{
    unsigned old_length = a.length();
    a.resize(a.length()*b);
    for(unsigned i = old_length ;i<a.length()*b; i++)
        a[i]=a[i%old_length];
    return a;
}
```

program crashes with error:

> *** Error in `./program': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000cd20b0 ***
>   Aborted

If I overload it like this - no error:

```
std::string operator*(std::string a, unsigned b)
{
    unsigned old_length = a.length();
    std::string a2 = a;
    a2.resize(a.length()*b);
    for(unsigned i = 0 ;i<a.length()*b; i++)
        a2[i]=a[i%old_length];
    return a2;
}
```

So where is the problem? Is there way not to create new string `a2`? It consumes additional memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string operator*(unsigned b, std::string a)
{
    return operator*(a, b);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string a = "abcdef "; // if string contains more than 4 symbols - free error for the first case
    std::string aaaa = 4*a;

    std::cout << a << "\n" 
              << aaaa << "\n" 
              << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't iterate until `a.length() * b` again (because it's equivalent to `old_length * b * b` after resizing).

The condition has to be either `i < a.length()` or `i < old_length * b`.

But why not use some of `std::string`'s functions?

```
std::string operator*(std::string a, unsigned b)
{
    a.reserve(a.length() * b);

    for(unsigned i = 1 ; i <= b; i++)
        a += a.substr(0, a.length() / b);

    return a;
}
```

We have also effectively eliminated `old_length` variable (not so effective on the performance side, see better approach in the comment below).

Comment: `auto n = a.length(); a.reserve(n * b); while(b--) a.append(a, 0, n);return a;` Should be better...

Comment: With some `const` in there, yeah

Answer (score 3):

Once you do `a.resize(a.length()*b);`

`a.length()` has changed.

Your loop should be than

```
for(unsigned i = old_length ;i<a.length(); i++)
```